# Error al momento de compilar con Flutter en Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, flutter, ubuntu

estoy haciendo mi primer CRUD. Me esta funcionando bien el CRUD con agregar, carga normal la ventana y agrega los datos a nivel funcional no hay ningún problema todo OK, estoy usando  **Visual Code** en **Ubuntu 22.04.3**  al momento de compilar en la terminal me sale este mensaje:

**(flet:209873): Gdk-CRITICAL: 13:34:02.849: gdk_window_get_state: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed**

A pesar de ese mensaje mi CRUD funciona normal pero ¿quisiera saber si ese mensaje tiene solución o si me traerá algún problema mas adelante ?